# Input validation (java) using GUI

Tags: java, validation, user-interface, exception

I'm creating (well, already created) a loan payment calculator using a GUI in Java.  Some of the calculations are wrong and I will fix them, so don't mind those.  What I'm really needing help with is the user input validation.  I tried using a try/catch block but I keep getting red underlines in NetBeans where the catch Exception is.  Why am I getting the underlines and is this the right type of validation?  Let me know if more code or info is needed.  Here is the main class/driver code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class LoanCalculator extends JFrame {
// Create text fields for interest rate, years
// loan amount, monthly payment, and total payment


private static final JTextField INTEREST_RATE = new JTextField();
private static final JTextField LOAN_YEARS = new JTextField();
private static final JTextField LOAN_AMOUNT = new JTextField();
private static final JTextField MONTHLY_PAYMENT = new JTextField();
private static final JTextField TOTAL_PAYMENT = new JTextField();

// Create a Compute Payment button
private static final JButton LOAN_COMPUTE = new JButton("Compute Payment");

public LoanCalculator() {
    // Panel p1 to hold labels and text fields
    //setSize (FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6, 2));
    labelPanel.add(new JLabel("Annual Interest Rate"));
    labelPanel.add(INTEREST_RATE);
    labelPanel.add(new JLabel("Number of Years"));
    labelPanel.add(LOAN_YEARS);
    labelPanel.add(new JLabel("Loan Amount"));
    labelPanel.add(LOAN_AMOUNT);
    labelPanel.add(new JLabel("Monthly Payment"));
    labelPanel.add(MONTHLY_PAYMENT);
    labelPanel.add(new JLabel("Total Payment"));
    labelPanel.add(TOTAL_PAYMENT);
    labelPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Enter loan amount, interest rate, and years"));

    // Panel p2 to hold the button
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
    buttonPanel.add(LOAN_COMPUTE);

    // Add the panels to the frame
    add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    // Register listener
    LOAN_COMPUTE.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
}

/**
 * Handle the Compute Payment button
 */
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Get values from text fields
    try{
        double interest = Double.parseDouble(INTEREST_RATE.getText());
        int year = Integer.parseInt(LOAN_YEARS.getText());
        double loanAmount = Double.parseDouble(LOAN_AMOUNT.getText());

        // Create a loan object
        Loan loan = new Loan(interest, year, loanAmount);

        // Display monthly payment and total payment
        MONTHLY_PAYMENT.setText(String.format("%.2f", loan.getMonthlyPayment()));
        TOTAL_PAYMENT.setText(String.format("%.2f", loan.getTotalPayment()));
    }catch (Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage(), "Error," , JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE));
    }           

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LoanCalculator frame = new LoanCalculator();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setTitle("LoanCalculator");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: The error message will *tell* you why you're getting the underlines. What is it telling you?

Comment: it says: "getMessage in class Throwable cannot be applied to given types

Comment: sorry, accidentally press Enter.  Also says" Required arguments: none" and "found: LoanCalculator.ButtonListener,String,String,int"

Comment: when you ask if anything in my try block throws an Exception, wouldn't something other than a double or int count as Throwable?  Or am I not making sense?  I'm still really new at this and not very good with the lingo yet :-)

Comment: I get this when I throw it into eclipse: The method showMessageDialog(Component, Object, String, int) in the type JOptionPane is not applicable for the arguments (NaturalNumber.ButtonListener, String, String, int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of the JOptionPane showMessageDialog method should be a GUI Component, and yours is not as it is instead the inner listener class. So change this:

```
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage(), 
        "Error,", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE));
```

to this:

```
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoanCalculator.this, ex.getMessage(), 
        "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); // extra parenthesis removed
```

As an aside, it's usually not a great idea to simply catch `Exception` as that would be casting your catch net over too large an area. Much better would be to catch specific and possibly expected exceptions.

Also, a lesson to be learned from this question is that you will want to read all error and exception messages carefully as they usually tell you exactly what is wrong and where, and usually are not that hard to understand.

Comment: Tried that, and I still get the same error message.

Comment: @kandaspohn: no, you get a different error message - you have too many end parenthesis  `))` on the end of the JOptionPane method. Again, read the error messages critically.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels: Perfect!! Works great!

Comment: public static void showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message)